# Where is the fallacy in Euler's formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Why can't we say the following is true for all $\theta$

$e^{i\theta} = \left[e^{i\theta}\right]^{\frac{2\pi}{2\pi}} = \left[e^{2i\pi}\right]^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = \left[1\right]^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}} = 1$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities

Comment: Euler's formula is fine.  But $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ is not (for complex numbers).

Comment: Every equality except for the second is legitimate. But in the second, there is an issue of switching between branches of the complex logarithm. Ultimately this branching issue causes $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ to fail in some situations in the complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The second equality is not true in $\mathbb{C}$, but only in $\mathbb{R}$. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities).

Answer (score 0):

This is analogous to:

$$\cos 0 = \cos{2\pi}\implies \pi = 0$$